# Нужна помощь в выравнивание svg элементов по высоте

Tags: html, css

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qmwc.png)HTML:

```html
         <div class="footer__icons">
              <div class="icons__icons">
                <img src="footer/1.svg" class="icons__vk" alt="vk">
              </div>
              <div class="icons__icons">
                <img src="footer/2.svg" alt="youtube">
              </div>
              <div class="icons__icons">
                <img src="footer/3.svg" alt="facebbok">
              </div>
              <div class="icons__icons">
                <img src="footer/4.svg" alt="inst">
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .footer__icons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .icons__icons {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: linear-gradient(94.26deg, #C89AFC 9.51%, #7C6AFA 90.23%);
      border-radius: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .icons__icons:not(:last-child){
      margin-right:30px;
    }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qmwc.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/62dVI.png `[![введите сюда код][1]][1]`

Comment: вы можете показать как в конечном итоге должен выглядеть результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
.footer__icons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .icons__icons {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: linear-gradient(94.26deg, #C89AFC 9.51%, #7C6AFA 90.23%);
      border-radius: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .icons__icons:not(:last-child){
      margin-right:30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="footer__icons">
        <div class="icons__icons">
          <img src="footer/1.svg" class="icons__vk" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="icons__icons">
          <img src="footer/2.svg" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="icons__icons">
          <img src="footer/3.svg" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="icons__icons">
          <img src="footer/4.svg" alt="1">
        </div>
      </div>

      
</body>
</html>
```